# Nav bar needs to know the routerLink value

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Angular 7 side-nav item is an anchor tag and app needs to know it's been routed to it.

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <a routerLink="pm/manage" />
  <app-another-component></app-another-component>
  <app-component-to-hide></app-component-to-hide>
</mat-nav-list>
```

My Angular 7 app has a side-nav bar. One of the nav items is an anchor tag with a routerLink attribute. The side-nav bar component needs to know that link was clicked and the app has routed to this part of the app. When this happens, the side-nav bar needs to hide the "app-component-to-hide".

Comment: Listen to your route changes and when you detect it routed to `pm/manage ` you can flip a flag or something that hides `app-component-to-hide`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the all route changes, then subscribe router event.
There are so many router events, and you can pick up any events you need.

And this is a sample code to subscribe NavigationEnd for the specific url :

```
constructor(private router: Router){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {

    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      console.log('Router change url event: ', this.router.url);

      if(this.router.url.indexOf('/pm/manage') > -1){
        //Do something
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I hope this will be helpful to you. :)